# Replacement when installing apk

Tags: android, installation, apk, replace

I'm facing a problem with installing an apk programatically.

I've got an android app which download apk files. Now I try to install these apk files using my android application.

I call the install intent but the system asks me to uninstall the main application before installing the downloaded file. Do you now why ?

Do I need more permissions than the lines below ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Below is how I start the install intent. The code is located in the doInBackground() method of an **AsyncTask**:

**fileUri** is the uri to the downloaded file. I got it using the **DownloadManager**
 activity is the  activity that executes the AsynchTask

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileUri),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    activity.startActivityF(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to silently install an app without asking the user to install, unless your app has root privileges.

Comment: The reason it asks to uninstall and reinstall might be due to version numbers?